# Itunes is playing songs in reverse order

Tags: macos, itunes

Does anyone know why my iTunes is playing songs in reverse order?

[image]

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8 with iTunes 10.3.1

Comment: Year 2016, iTunes v12.4 and this problem still exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back.

For some reason, it seems to happen whenever you sort albums in descending order.

What fixed it for me was going to the album overview (the grid with all the covers), then selecting

```
View -> Sort Albums -> Ascending.
```

After that, the playback order within the individual albums went back to normal.

Hope this works for you as well.

[image: Screenshot of iTunes Menu]

Comment: This is really weird behaviour (or imho a bug, really) and worse still and what's worse it's still present in iTunes 12.